# JavaScript/jQuery : One ID, two functions. How can I do this with minimal code duplication?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I've got an ID and I'd like to assign two functions to it. Here's what it currently looks like:

```
document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", this._dropFiles, false);
document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", this._handleFileDrop, false);
```

How can I rewrite this file without so much duplication?

I tried doing

```
document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", this._dropFiles, this._handleFileDrop, false);
```

and

```
document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", function(){this._dropFiles; this._handleFileDrop}, false);
```

All to no avail :(
jQuery solutions are allowed

Comment: Loops? Variables? Is it just the two? If so, then is it really a problem? Passing random extra arguments to a well-defined function certainly isn't a solution

Comment: It's just those two functions - what I'm wanting is to be able to attach both of them to the ID with one line rather than having to rewrite the whole thing again.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more performant:

```
var dragArea = document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea);
dragArea.addEventListener("drop", function () {
  that._dropFiles();
  that._handleFileDrop();
}, false);
```

If you had a lot of event listeners then you could make some sort of loop that assigns a whole bunch of this._doX functions, but for just these two listeners, that'd probably be overly complex.

With jQuery:

```
var dragArea = $(this.config.dragArea);
var that = this;
dragArea.on("drop", function () {
  that._dropFiles();
  that._handleFileDrop();
});
```

Comment: Hmm..What about if I used jQuery? I've edited the question to allow jQuery Solutions.

Comment: Added a jQuery solution. It isn't really any more complicated than the vanilla JS solution. In retrospect, you could probably use an anonymous function that calls both functions in either case. Updating now...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want something dryer...

```
[this._dropFiles, this._handleFileDrop].forEach(function(fun){
    document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop", fun);
});
```

Note that a shim for `forEach` is required on IE8.

You could also more reasonnably simply store `document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea)` in a variable and reuse it.